# Nested Inner/Outer Joins with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have an routine (Vb.net app) that fills a datagridview programmatically from sql queries, using one master query and then another set of (sub)queries (one for each row generated by the master query).

My vb code is probably quite weak as well, but I have a question on the sql code, as I am issuing multiple queries and I usually manage to use UNIONs and JOINs to reduce it to one query but I am failing on this problem.  I sense that I may be missing some fundamental principles.

Right now, my first QUERY creates a datatable with many rows.  The GroupBy field has many possibilities, and here is an example using Employee

```
select T.EmployeeID, sum(t.tehours) as 'Hours'
from TimeEntry as t 
inner join Project as p on p.projectid=t.ProjectID
inner join employee as E on E.Employeeid=t.employeeid 
inner join Activity as A on A.activityid=t.activityid
 where p.active=1 AND t.tedate >='8/1/2015' and e.empother1='OFC1'
  and a.discipline='X' and t.projectid not like 'O-%' 
 GROUP BY T.EmployeeID with rollup  order by hours desc
```

```
SAMPLE RESULTS:  

GROUPBY    HOURS  
George     10.0  
Fred       19.2  
Jose        4.4  
TOTAL      33.6
```

Then, I run a loop in vb to get total invoices (if any) for each row, where invoice date is in same date range as the time entry.  So, here is the query for the first row above where E.EmployeeID='George'

```
select sum(TT.ServiceAmt) as 'Invoiced' 
   from TransactionTable as TT 
   WHERE TT.InvoiceDate>-'08/01/2015' AND 
   TT.PROJECTID in 
           (select t.projectid from TimeEntry as t 
           inner join Project as p on p.projectid=t.ProjectID
           inner join employee as E on E.Employeeid=t.employeeid 
           inner join Activity as A on A.activityid=t.activityid
           where p.active=1 AND t.tedate >='8/1/2015' and e.empother1='OFC1'
           and e.employeeID='GEORGE'
           and a.discipline='X' and t.projectid not like 'O-%' )
```

This results in either a null string or a value.  If null, zero is substituted.  By running this query for each row in the original RESULTS, we gain a table that looks like this:

```
GROUPBY    HOURS    INVOICED  
George     10.0      $1000  
Fred       19.2      $1000  
Jose        4.4         $0  
TOTAL      33.6      $1000
```

If the invoice was a fixed fee, it is not defined per employee.   So, the total may be $1000 not $2000 if the invoice$ noted under George and Fred is from the same invoice.   If it is a different invoice, then it is $2000.

Note: when the leftmost column (GROUPBY) uses ProjectID, this is relatively easy, as that field exists in the invoice transaction table.   My example specifically avoids this, because this is the problem I am trying to solve.

My code "works" now, but I would like to avoid the slow loop.  Perhaps I can't given the complexity and flexibility.

Comment: It is not completely clear what is going on in your code. Specifically, 1. if you create a table with the first query, where is it referenced in the second query? 2. What does ` ... same conditions as above` mean? 3. Sample data (for tables in the second query) and expected results will improve your question. 4 Are you concerned with speed or wrong results?

Comment: Could you possibly create a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with table structure, and some sample data. And the expected output for the data supplied?

Comment: @bulat - I tried to edit the question to remove ambiguity.  Thanks for the suggestions on sample data.   My results are fine, the speed is annoying but not sooo bad (10 seconds, and about 90% is due to number of queries I think).  Perhaps I just need to live with it, or take a hard look at the vb side.

Comment: Your approach is quite heavy with potential problems in results. Can you post your schema as well with links between tables. It looks strange that you can bring `INVOICED` number to the employee level.

Comment: Is it possible that several people work on the same project? Does your Transactions link billing to employee?

Comment: Yes, it would be faster to have one query than n queries, so go with that approach - and you probably handle the 'roll up' aspect in your application. Is 8/1/2015 something that m$sql understands?

Comment: It is not my schema and it can not be changed, but I understand and appreciate the feedback.   It looks to me like I can at least take the 2nd set of multiple queries and concatenate them with a UNION command and then do an inner join with the two data sets.   Otherwise, since users pick GROUPBY, I can choose to not display the number for tricky GROUPBYs like this one.  That is what I did originally, but I wondered if there was a reasonable way to show it.  Looks like most say NOT LOGICAL, which I understand.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - MS Sql   2008.   Guess I need to edit that sql tag

Answer (score 0):

It seems that first query provides your with result at the wrong level and you have to inject it again into the second query.

Instead, you could change first query to this:

```
select p.ProjectId, T.EmployeeID, sum(t.tehours) as 'Hours'
from TimeEntry as t 
inner join Project as p on p.projectid=t.ProjectID
inner join employee as E on E.Employeeid=t.employeeid 
inner join Activity as A on A.activityid=t.activityid
 where p.active=1 AND t.tedate >='8/1/2015' and e.empother1='OFC1'
  and a.discipline='X' and t.projectid not like 'O-%' 
 GROUP BY p.ProjectId, T.EmployeeID with rollup  order by hours desc
```

And in the second query use ProjectID values directly:

```
SELECT SUM(TT.ServiceAmt) AS 'Invoiced' 
FROM TransactionTable as TT 
WHERE TT.InvoiceDate>-'08/01/2015' AND 
   TT.PROJECTID = <ID of a Project from first query>
```

Few questions on the business rules and schema:

- Is it possible that several people work on the same project?
- Does your `Transactions` table have a reference to `Employee` table?

Your approach looks wrong all together, as depending on the answer to questions above you will only be able to present correct information for billing by project.

Comment: Q:  (1) yes.   (2) No

Comment: Q:  (1) yes.   (2) well, yes, but one to one for who ran the invoice, not one to many for who worked on it.   Users pick GROUPBY in the app, and yes, the vastly easier approach is to insist on GROUPBY be a field that is one to one with invoices like project id.  But... the number provides a checksum and answers the question did my work get invoiced.   If you click the number, the invoices are listed in a table.   The table sum equals the number.   Partly, I am trying to understand sql coding as well, so I appreciate your effort here.

Comment: So it seems that my answer provides you with results that user should see after he clicks the number. Without more details about your schema, process and expected result its difficult to give more specific answer.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took walking me through the issues, although your first query is not ideal for me.  At that point, you are answering a different question, but I do not want group by projectid here.   I will see if I can use UNION to generate one large second query instead of many second queries, and then using LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much does what I want and runs quickly.  I can use whatever GROUP BY I want and it is one query.  Thanks for helping me think it through.

```
SELECT WORKED.GroupBY, WORKED.Hours, WORKED.Effort, WORKED.Billable, WORKED.COST, INV.invoiced 
FROM (
      select T.EmployeeID as 'GroupBy', sum(t.tehours) as 'Hours'
      from TimeEntry as t 
      inner join Project as p on p.projectid=t.ProjectID
      inner join employee as E on E.Employeeid=t.employeeid 
      inner join Activity as A on A.activityid=t.activityid
       where p.active=1 AND t.tedate >='8/1/2015' and e.empother1='OFC1'
        and a.discipline='X' and t.projectid not like 'O-%' 
       GROUP BY T.EmployeeID with rollup 

 ) as WORKED 

 LEFT JOIN 

( select T.EmployeeID as 'GroupBy', sum(TT.ServiceAmt)/count(T.EmployeeID) as 'Invoiced' 
   from TransactionTable as TT 
   inner join TimeEntry as T on T.ProjectID=TT.ProjectID
   inner join Project as p on p.projectid=t.ProjectID
   inner join employee as E on E.Employeeid=t.employeeid 
   inner join Activity as A on A.activityid=t.activityid

   WHERE TT.InvoiceDate>-'08/01/2015' AND 
   TT.PROJECTID in 
           (select t.projectid from TimeEntry as t 
           inner join Project as p on p.projectid=t.ProjectID
           inner join employee as E on E.Employeeid=t.employeeid 
           inner join Activity as A on A.activityid=t.activityid
           where p.active=1 AND t.tedate >='8/1/2015' and e.empother1='OFC1'
           and e.employeeID='GEORGE'
           and a.discipline='X' and t.projectid not like 'O-%'
              GROUP BY T.EmployeeID with rollup )
) 
      as INV on WORKED.GroupBY=INV.GroupBY
ORDER BY Hours DESC
```